# How to implement different types in Java

Tags: java, python, types, casting

I have the following code in Python, I'm just wondering if there is a way to implement similar feature in Java:

```
class TypeOperator(object):
"""An n-ary type constructor which builds a new type from old"""

    def __init__(self, name, types):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types

    def __str__(self):
        num_types = len(self.types)
        if num_types == 0:
            return self.name
        elif num_types == 2:
            return "({0} {1} {2})".format(str(self.types[0]), self.name, str(self.types[1]))
        else:
            return "{0} {1}" .format(self.name, ' '.join(self.types))


class Function(TypeOperator):
"""A binary type constructor which builds function types"""

    def __init__(self, from_type, to_type):
        super(Function, self).__init__("->", [from_type, to_type])

my_env = {"pair": Function(var1, Function(var2, pair_type)),
          "true": Bool,
          "cond": Function(Bool, Function(var3, Function(var3, var3))),
          "zero": Function(Integer, Bool),
          "pred": Function(Integer, Integer),
          "times": Function(Integer, Function(Integer, Integer))}
```

What I've done for now in Java is:

```
class TypeOperator extends TypeExp{
    private String operator;
    private TypeList types;
    public TypeOperator(String operator, TypeList types){
        this.operator = operator;
        this.types = types;
    }

    public static TypeExp newTypeOperator(String operator, TypeList types) {
        return new TypeOperator(operator, types);
    }
}

class Function extends TypeOperator{
    private static final String x = "->";
    private TypeList listOfTypes;
    public Function(String x, TypeList listOfTypes){
        super(x, listOfTypes);
    }

    public static TypeExp newFunction(TypeList listOfTypes){
        return new Function("->", listOfTypes);
    }
}

public class TypeExp{
}

public class TypeList extends LinkedList<Object>{
}
```

But I can not find a way to deal with the class function because it takes TypeList as 2nd parameter but in the python code, it can take Function as 2nd parameter which is why I find it difficult.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: In java you can't have a function as a parameter. You can however have something like....
print(getInt());

Comment: incompatible types: TypeExp cannot be converted to TypeList

Comment: When I put your Java code in my IDE, I don't get that error.  It builds fine.  Try a full *clean* and then *build* your full project from scratch.  Could be some artifacts confusing the IDE syntax checker.